# Appending object of one XML file to another XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am doing object detection, in which I have two XML files I want to append the XML objects not present in the XML file to new XML files.

Please help me with this. I have written a code that creates the object architecture if anybody can help me with appending that object in another XML that would be great.

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

Old_XML_Location = "..."
New_XML_Location = "..."

for new_xml_file in glob.glob(New_XML_Location + '/*.xml'):
    for old_xml_file in glob.glob(Old_XML_Location + '/*.xml'):
        print(old_xml_file)
        if os.path.basename(new_xml_file) == os.path.basename(old_xml_file):
            #xml_list = []
            tree = ET.parse(new_xml_file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for member in root.findall('object'):
                print(member[0].text)
                #if member[0].text == "Time":
                value = (member[0].text,
                         int(member[4][0].text),
                         int(member[4][1].text),
                         int(member[4][2].text),
                         int(member[4][3].text)
                         )
                xlobject=ET.Element("object")
                root.append(xlobject)
                xlbname=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"name")
                xlbname.text = value[0]
                pose=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"pose")
                pose.text="Unspecified"        
                truncate=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"truncated")
                truncate.text="0"        
                difficult=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"difficult")
                difficult.text="0"    
                bndbox=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"bndbox")
                tree = ET.ElementTree(root)        
                xlxmin=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"xmin")
                xlxmin.text=str(int(value[1]))         
                xlymin=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"ymin")
                xlymin.text=str(int(value[2]))        
                xlxax=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"xmax")
                xlxax.text=str(int(value[3]))        
                xlymax=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"ymax")
                xlymax.text=str(int(value[4]))
                tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
                tree.write(old_xml_file)
                # with open(old_xml_file, "w") as fh:
                #   fh.write(tree)
                # else :
                #   print("False")
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, exactly?

Comment: Its adding the object twice in the generated XML file.

Comment: Alright, have you done anything to try to solve this?

Comment: I am trying but till now I didn't get any success!!

Comment: You might find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

So far by using your code and little googling I have combined xmls for class ball and no-ball. 
Here is the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Apr  6 06:24:41 2020

@author: sahab
"""


import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

for new_xml_file in glob.glob(r'E:\Cricket\Cricket\ball\*.xml'):
    for old_xml_file in glob.glob(r'E:\Cricket\Cricket\noball\\' + os.path.basename(new_xml_file)):
            print(old_xml_file)
            old_tree = ET.parse(old_xml_file)
            old_root = old_tree.getroot()
            tree = ET.parse(new_xml_file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for member in root.findall('object'):
                print(member[0].text)
                #if member[0].text == "Time":
                value = (member[0].text,
                          int(member[4][0].text),
                          int(member[4][1].text),
                          int(member[4][2].text),
                          int(member[4][3].text)
                          )
                print(value)
                xlobject=ET.Element("object")
                xlbname=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"name")
                xlbname.text = value[0]
                pose=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"pose")
                pose.text="Unspecified"        
                truncate=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"truncated")
                truncate.text="0"        
                difficult=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"difficult")
                difficult.text="0"    
                bndbox=ET.SubElement(xlobject,"bndbox")
                tree = ET.ElementTree(root)        
                xlxmin=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"xmin")
                xlxmin.text=str(int(value[1]))         
                xlymin=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"ymin")
                xlymin.text=str(int(value[2]))        
                xlxax=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"xmax")
                xlxax.text=str(int(value[3]))        
                xlymax=ET.SubElement(bndbox,"ymax")
                xlymax.text=str(int(value[4]))
                old_root.append(xlobject)
            with open(r'E:\Cricket\Cricket\combined\\' +os.path.basename(new_xml_file), "w") as fh:
                tree = ET.ElementTree(old_root)
                r = old_tree.getroot()
                print (ET.tostring(r))
                fh.write(ET.tostring(r).decode("utf-8"))
```